# Optimizing many require_once calls

Tags: php

I have a website that has about 150 require_once calls in a "catalog" page. Each page calls require_once on this catalog to make sure all necessary files are loaded. Calling require_once on this catalog takes somewhere between 5 and 15 seconds, and I have no easy way to reduce the number of classes each page needs.

So: is there any way to speed up this process? I assume it will need to be done once, but I also assumed it would be cached for the session, which doesn't seem to be the case since this 5-15 second overhead is the same on every single page load.

Hopefully this makes sense.

Thanks!

Comment: 150 included libraries?! In any case, are you using fastCGI or php-eaccelerator? It should help substantially.

Comment: I'm not really sure where, because you don't give many details, but I'm pretty sure there is some logic flaw. A catalog would probably consist of hundreds of items pulled from the DB I just don't see why you're including a file with each item...

Comment: a) Make sure you're using an opcode cache like APC. b) Use xdebug (or another tool) and profile your application. You'll be able to locate your bottleneck pretty fast.

Comment: I was trying to avoid profilers and other server side modifications because I'm pretty limited in scope on what changes I can make to the server. I added autoloading now, which substantially sped it up for a while but then it seems to drop the loaded files from whatever cache is being used, and it slows down again. It looks like php-eaccelerator is exactly what I'm looking for at this point, so I'll look into that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind require_once is to make sure:

1. You don't have the file more than once.
2. Make load times faster so that the file isn't included again.

PHP stores in memory what files have already been loaded. If you call require_once on a file and then call it again, PHP won't even look for the file, it'll see that it's already been loaded and won't bother to read the file.

This makes me think that require_once isn't the culprit of your page load issues.

However, I may  be misunderstanding the question. If you mean that each require_once is different, then that's another story. IF they are used to load classes, check out the PHP autoload function. [PHP: Autoloading Classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php). This will only load the classes that are called upon.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that you have some logic defined in one of your required scripts.  If they were all just class definition files, there's no reason requiring them would take 5-15 seconds.

Is there some reason you're including every class on every page?  You should look into [autoloading classes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) instead, if possible.